# MVC model validation with complex model (virtual member)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, validation

I have a model:

```
public class Student : AbstractDomainObject 
{
    public Student() 
    {
        Guardians = new HashSet<Guardian>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Birthdate is required.")]
    public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Guardian> Guardians { get; set; }
}
```

The guardian model is:

```
public partial class Guardian : AbstractDomainObject 
{
    private string _homePhone;
    private string _cellPhone;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    public string Relationship { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Guardian First Name is required.")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

In my HTML I have

```
<div class="col-2"><label class="required">First Name:</label></div>
<div class="col-4">
    <input type="text" class="textBox" asp-for="FirstName" id="FirstName" 
     tabindex="4">
     <span class="required">*</span>
     <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>}
```

and a little later

```
<div class="row with-margin">
<div class="col-4">
    <label for="Guardians.FirstOrDefault<Guardian>().FirstName" class="required">Parent First Name:</label>
    </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <input type="text" class="textBox" asp-for="Guardians.FirstOrDefault<Guardian>().FirstName" id="ParentFirstName" tabindex="16">
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <span asp-validation-for="Guardians.FirstOrDefault<Guardian>().FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
```

When the Student First Name is empty and Guardian First Name is filled out, validation message appears for BOTH Student First Name (as expected) and Parent First Name (even though it has a valid value).
When inspecting HTML both fields have name FirstName. Changing the Guardian model "FirstName" would be brutal

Help

Answer (score 0):

> When the Student First Name is empty and Guardian First Name is filled out, validation message appears for BOTH Student First Name (as expected) and Parent First Name (even though it has a valid value). When inspecting HTML both fields have name FirstName. Changing the Guardian model "FirstName" would be brutal

Yes, as you said, the `asp-validation-for="Guardians.FirstOrDefault<Guardian>().FirstName"` and `asp-validation-for="FirstName"` will generate the same value for attribute `data-valmsg-for`. Also the input for `Guardian` is also generated incorrect name attribute and would not working for further form post.

You can change your model property to type of `List` instead of `ICollection`, then you can use `Guardians[0].FirstName` in your view which will generate the correct `name` and `data-valmsg-for`.

Model:

```
public class Student : AbstractDomainObject
{
    public Student()
    {
        Guardians = new List<Guardian>(); //change here...
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    //.....
    public virtual List<Guardian> Guardians { get; set; }  //change here...
}
```

View:

```
@model Student
<form method="post">
    <div class="col-2"><label class="required">First Name:</label></div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <input type="text" class="textBox" asp-for="FirstName" id="FirstName"
               tabindex="4">
        <span class="required">*</span>
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row with-margin">
        <div class="col-4">
            <label for="Guardians[0].FirstName" class="required">Parent First Name:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <input type="text" class="textBox" asp-for="Guardians[0].FirstName" id="ParentFirstName" tabindex="16">
            <span class="required">*</span>
            <span asp-validation-for="Guardians[0].FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <input type=submit value="Create" />
</form>
```

Result:

[image]